# Nginx + PHP-FPM ignores no-cache headers

Tags: php, cache, nginx

I'm using the following header on a php page.

```
 // Prevent page caching.
 header('Expires: Tue, 20 Oct 1981 05:00:00 GMT'); 
 header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
 header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE); 
 header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

I'm also using a rand=999999999 (with a real random number) in the URLs.

But pages are still being cached. Reload works, but first load is cached. Anyone know where I can change this?

Answer (score 1):

You send a duplicate "Cache-Control" header. Try removing the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Check NGINX settings. Might be there something like

```
proxy_ignore_headers  "Cache-Control" "Expires";
```